Implementing a modern plot format in Matplotlib
I came across a particular plot format that really caught my eye, and I'm keen on implementing it using Matplotlib, both for single axes and twin axes; however, my attempts thus far have had limited success. While it seems totally feasible to create this format with static code for individual plots, making it dynamic to accommodate arbitrary x and y data has proven challenging (to me, lol). I've been playing with get/set_x/y_ticks and set_bounds method of the spine object. I've had no luck adapting them dynamically. Since I generate numerous plots for work, primarily simple curve plots, I would really like to set up this theme for all my plots.
I'm not set on using Matplotlib exclusively; I also use Plotly as well. I discovered the set_bounds method and thought I could get somehwere with it.


BTW, here is the article where I saw these plots.
This is what I attempted. It's pretty basic stuff, but you can see I was just starting to lose my thought process when I tried to adjust the x-axis dynamically. I ended up using if/else statements to handle various scenarios at the lower and upper ends of the axes. I got overwhelmed just thinking about it and figured I would ask here first to find out if there are any other exisitng helpful methods. If there are, please let me know before I spend my entire upcoming weekend trying to implement this. For some reason, I really like this format and can't stop thinking about it. Haha! I'm a total sucker for clean plots.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4.5]
y = [1, 2, 5, 1.8, 12]
ax.plot(x, y, linestyle='-')

# figure out only single axes fomrat first.
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)


x_min, x_max = min(x), max(x)
y_min, y_max = min(y), max(y)

y_ticks = ax.get_yticks()
x_ticks = ax.get_xticks()
print(x_ticks)

clearance_x = (x_ticks[1]-x_ticks[0])*0.25
clearance_y = (y_ticks[1]-y_ticks[0])*0.25

# --- format y-axis. Static for now.

# if y_min < y_ticks[1]:
ylim_low_bound = y_ticks[0] - clearance_y
yspine_low_bound = y_ticks[0]
# ax.set_ylim(ylim_low_bound, y_max)
# else:
#     yspine_low_bound = ylim_low_bound = y_min

yspine_high_bound = y_ticks[-1]
ax.set_ylim(ylim_low_bound, yspine_high_bound)

# --- format x-axis. attempting to make it dynamic.

if x_min < x_ticks[1]:
    xlim_low_bound = x_ticks[0] - clearance_x
    xspine_low_bound = x_ticks[0]
elif x_min == x_ticks[1]:
    xlim_low_bound = x_ticks[1] - clearance_x
    xspine_low_bound = x_ticks[1]
else:
    xlim_low_bound = x_ticks[1] - clearance_x
    xspine_low_bound = x_ticks[1]

if x_max < x_ticks[-1]:
    ax.set_xlim(xlim_low_bound)
    xspine_high_bound = ax.get_xticks()[-1]
    # ax.set_xlim(xlim_low_bound, xspine_high_bound)
# elif x_max == x_ticks[-2]:
else:
    new_x_ticks = ax.get_xticks()
    xspine_high_bound = new_x_ticks[-1]
    ax.set_xlim(xlim_low_bound, xspine_high_bound)
    print(new_x_ticks)  # check if ticks position changes (yes)

# F this....this is impossible.

ax.spines['left'].set_bounds(yspine_low_bound, yspine_high_bound)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_bounds(xspine_low_bound, xspine_high_bound)

ax.tick_params(direction='out', width=1.5, length=5, which="both")

for axis in ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']:
    ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(1.5)

# later problem ... for twin axes...
# ax.spines['right'].set_bounds(yspine_low_bound, yspine_high_bound)

plt.show()

The above code gives me this. Intentionally not showing the points. I usually just plot the "curve".


This seems kind of vague for Stack Overflow. Either you should be much more specific about what isn't working, or if it's all working and you have design trouble then move to Code Review.

IIUC, ax2 = ax.twinx() then plot the GDP per capita on ax and the GDP on ax2. If this is not your question, then please be explicit, explain the exact problem (e.g. "how to have 2 independent axes?", reproducing the plot in general is lacking focus).

@mozway I think this post is primarily about adjusting the spines. Not sure the dupe target is relevant.

@BigBen could be, but then the question might need to be simplified to emphasize this.
